# Android Studio Not Opening After updating to 3.1

Tags: android-studio

My A.S was working normally but after the update nothing works :(
when i opened  A.S the process appears in task manager then it disappears within 10 seconds
launching it via studio.bat cause "OpenJDK Platform binary has stopped working"
my old A.S version was 3.0
please any way to fix this or restore the old 1??
Thanks